# Downloading a file via selenium through Jenkins and download is cancelled?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am running a python script which opens a chrome browser via selenium, navigates to a page, and clicks a link which downloads a csv file.

I can run this script locally and everything works as expected. If I instead run the script through my Jenkins pipeline, the file is not downloaded. I've printed out the driver's performance logs, and I see that the download does start, but is eventually cancelled:

```js
{'message': {
  'method': 'Page.downloadProgress',
  'params': {
    'guid': '450ca6e7-b457-440c-b344-c9c672c46963',
    'receivedBytes': 0,
    'state': 'inProgress',
    'totalBytes': 0
  }
}, 'webview': 'B64F8253B02AB1AED58E1A976EECECC2'} 
{'message': {
    'method': 'Page.downloadProgress',
    'params': {
      'guid': '450ca6e7-b457-440c-b344-c9c672c46963',
      'receivedBytes': 119233,
      'state': 'inProgress',
      'totalBytes': 0
    }
  },
  'webview': 'B64F8253B02AB1AED58E1A976EECECC2'} 
 {'message': {
    'method': 'Page.downloadProgress',
    'params': {
      'guid': '450ca6e7-b457-440c-b344-c9c672c46963',
      'receivedBytes': 0,
      'state': 'canceled',
      'totalBytes': 0
    }
  },
  'webview': 'B64F8253B02AB1AED58E1A976EECECC2'}
```

The logs look like this when I run it locally:

```js
{
  'message': {
    'method': 'Page.downloadProgress',
    'params': {
      'guid': '393fac4c-527e-4c7d-829f-6b23c1232260',
      'receivedBytes': 0,
      'state': 'inProgress',
      'totalBytes': 0
    }
  },
  'webview': '929F090474357DB72423ECF9A5260AC8'
} {
  'message': {
    'method': 'Page.downloadProgress',
    'params': {
      'guid': '393fac4c-527e-4c7d-829f-6b23c1232260',
      'receivedBytes': 135665,
      'state': 'inProgress',
      'totalBytes': 0
    }
  },
  'webview': '929F090474357DB72423ECF9A5260AC8'
} {
  'message': {
    'method': 'Page.downloadProgress',
    'params': {
      'guid': '393fac4c-527e-4c7d-829f-6b23c1232260',
      'receivedBytes': 135665,
      'state': 'inProgress',
      'totalBytes': 0
    }
  },
  'webview': '929F090474357DB72423ECF9A5260AC8'
} {
  'message': {
    'method': 'Page.downloadProgress',
    'params': {
      'guid': '393fac4c-527e-4c7d-829f-6b23c1232260',
      'receivedBytes': 135665,
      'state': 'inProgress',
      'totalBytes': 135665
    }
  },
  'webview': '929F090474357DB72423ECF9A5260AC8'
} {
  'message': {
    'method': 'Page.downloadProgress',
    'params': {
      'guid': '393fac4c-527e-4c7d-829f-6b23c1232260',
      'receivedBytes': 135665,
      'state': 'inProgress',
      'totalBytes': 135665
    }
  },
  'webview': '929F090474357DB72423ECF9A5260AC8'
} {
  'message': {
    'method': 'Page.downloadProgress',
    'params': {
      'guid': '393fac4c-527e-4c7d-829f-6b23c1232260',
      'receivedBytes': 135665,
      'state': 'completed',
      'totalBytes': 135665
    }
  },
  'webview': '929F090474357DB72423ECF9A5260AC8'
}
```

I am setting the default download path of files via ChromeOptions():

```js
from selenium import webdriver

options = ChromeOptions()
download_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'tmp_downloads')
if not os.path.exists(download_path):
  os.makedirs(download_path)
chrome_prefs = {
  "download.default_directory": download_path,
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", chrome_prefs)
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

I'm guessing there is some settings in jenkins that I need to change to allow files to be downloaded? I am not sure what else could be cancelling the download.

Comment: Does the jenkins server have the download directory ```tmp_downloads```. If not, as part of your script, it looks like there maybe a permissions problem allowing the directory to be created if it does not exist.

Are you using the main jenkins node, or are you using a docker agent etc. - you need to check permissions for both

Comment: @djmonki yes I confirmed that the `tmp_downloads` directory is created and does exist. I'm using a docker agent, I am not sure how to check if it has proper permissions to write to the directory, although I assume it would if since it created the directory?

Comment: Doing some more checking it does seem like it has proper read/write permissions. I'm printing out `os.access(/path/to/tmp_downloads, os.W_OK)` and `os.access(/path/to/tmp_downloads, os.R_OK)` and both are returning True

Comment: Is your jenkins job scripted, if so can you provide your jenkinsfile also showing your docker agent setup. Also how are you providing chrome browser,  is that with a browser installed on the Docker agent or are you running a Docker selenium grid separately?